# NodeJS: Check if day is sunday - TZ offset problem

Tags: node.js

I would like to restrict some actions if date is on sunday - e.g. do not allow create item on Sunday.

I use:

```
public isSunday(date: Date): boolean {   
  return date.getDay() === 0; 
}
```

My problem is that my UTC offset is UTC+2.
Server and database runs on UTC TZ to prevent unwanted date and time shifts.

When I send datetime from frontend I use date.toISOString(), so my local datetime

> 2022-05-16 00:00:00 is converted to string 2022-05-15T22:00:00:000Z

When I check this date on the backend side, this date IS sunday, but in the UTC zone, not my local zone.

String value is converted to Date at the backend using following
`new Date(input);`

Edit: Value `2022-05-16T01:41:00+02:00` (sending value with utc offset info) does not work either

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you need the local (UTC+2) zone on the back-end for only Sunday checks.

You can simply subtract 2 hours equal to milliseconds from the date received on the backend before the Sunday checks.

```
// ... get date here
date -= (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // subtract 2 hours
```

Comment: This might not be the best idea. 2 hours offset is just for user from my timezone. Users from different timezones would might still have this problem.

Comment: Then user timezone information is needed additionally, it could be sent inside the request as a new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good practice as your frontend may change its timezone but you can try this.

```
const date = new Date("2022-05-16 00:00:00")
const corrected_date = new Date(date.valueOf() - 7200000) //subtract milliseconds as needed, in this case 2*60*60*1000
console.log(corrected_date.getDay())
```

If possible, then you should maybe try sending the UTC offset as a seperate parameter to the backend and calculate the correct value to be subtracted for it to work dynamically.